# startx not starting when you want to write its log

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have set up a very minimal linux. No desktop environment just window manager. I used i3 as window manager and set up X to start it;

upon login I want startx to run

so I added this code on .bash_profile

```
 startx >> $HOME/.startx.log 2>&1 && exit
```

after login the system just do nothing(something like freeze but still the cursor blinks). it seems that it is waiting for input.

if I change the command to this

```
 startx && exit
```

it just starts perfectly

anyone know why?